# How to extract text information from specified places using OCR?

Tags: python, node.js, artificial-intelligence, ocr

User uploads tabular data with information like classes, professors, schedule and such.

I want to easily extract that information.

I can use an OCR library, but it'd simply output text as randomly mixed.

I would have no idea what something belongs to.

Is there a way to train OCR little bit to only look at certain part of image (form) and then label data so when it extracts it's all labeled. etc

Suppose i had a form with lots of data, I want it to only look at address section and label it.

Or it spreadsheet like data and i want it to label it by columns.

Simply extract all text into string isn't that useful.

Comment: It seems to me that the central problem here is locating stuff on the page. Once you know where it is, you can extract a rectangle & use OCR to get the text in that rectangle. So, the real question here is how to recognize the parts of the page that you want.

Comment: lamest solution i can do is have user draw boxes on top of image and label them, i guess step up then typing

Comment: I agree, but my point is that you haven't answered that basic question: how does your app know which regions of the image are important? If you can do that programmatically, great, you're more than halfway there. If you can't then you need to answer that question first. My comment was intended to get you thinking about the question in a different way because, as written, it is unanswerable.

Comment: i want ocr to detect rows in table, also note that images are not likely to be a perfect, they could be rotated in all axis a little bit

Answer (score 0):

If every document have the same format. 
Try dissect the document into individual part and feed OCR the part that you need the text.
If not, good luck, I'm looking for the answer too.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't add "Me too" as answers, as it doesn't actually provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then ask it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you're interested in this specific question, you can upvote it, leave a comment, or start a bounty once you have enough reputation.

Comment: problem would be that if page is slightly rotated then it'd be all wrong, i guess with certain transformation that some camera apps apply, like office lens, it could be mitigated. but i've no clue how to do those matrix transformation or object detection.

Comment: Thanks for the advice ricky3350, I'm new here. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: I think both Tesseract and Libtesseract have orientation detection function and can be use with PyOCR but I haven't try it.